# Limitar o valor máximo de um input number e ao mesmo tempo mostrar esse valor em um input text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um formulário onde para cada tipo de despesa haverá um valor limite a ser enviado pelo usuário. O que estou utilizando no meu formulário é o tipo da despesa (sendo uma option), o valor da despesa a ser enviada pelo usuário (sendo um number) e usei um readonly com, por exemplo, "Limite de R$30".

O problema é que esse valor iria alterar conforme o usuário fosse mudando o tipo de despesa. Por exemplo:
Supondo que o usuário selecione despesa X que tem como limite R$20

- Se ele selecionar essa despesa, só poderá colocar no campo de valor (que está habilitado pelo ) o máximo de R$20, mais do que isso irá ficar preenchido os R$20.

No meu código abaixo, fiz apenas o teste para que haja este campo onde o usuário não consegue alterar (no caso o "Limite de R$30").

```
<select name="tipoDespesa" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Tipo</option>
        <option>Almoço</option>
        <option>Jantar</option> 

</select>
        <input type="number" name="precoDespesa" placeholder="R$" id="valor" step=".01" required placeholder="Insira um valor!">
        <p><input type="text" name="limiteDespesa" id="limite" readonly value="Limite de R$30"></p>
```

Comment: O que você quer é: mudar o valor do segundo input conforme o que for selecionado no select?

Comment: Sim, essa seria a primeira etapa. A segunda é que, de acordo com o valor do segundo input que vai ser alterado, eu não possa ultrapassar esse valor no primeiro input.

Comment: Isso não é uma questão relacionada ao php e sim a tecnologia front-end que você está usando. Qual seria essa? html/css/js/jquery/vue..?

Comment: eu estou utilizando o html para o formulário, e para os estilos o css. desculpe, sou iniciante, mas acho que é essa a resposta

Comment: Sugiro que dê uma olhada numa linguagem chamda javascript. _Com o JS, você pode mostrar mensagens e outras informações interessantes, fazer verificações ou mudar dinamicamente a apresentação visual das páginas, conforme o comportamento que você deseja que sua página (ou aplicação) possua._

Comment: Com javascript você consegue alterar facilmente os values e atributos do input

Comment: mas eu posso colocar direto no código embaixo algo com javascript? ou teria q refazer todo meu código...

Comment: Vai precisar de  jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a melhor forma de fazer isso é com Javascript, pois com ele você pode pegar o evento de quando o usuário altera o tipo de despesa e usar para alterar valores de outros campo sem a necessidade de enviar para o servidor.

```
<select name="tipoDespesa" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Tipo</option>
<option>Almoço</option>
<option>Jantar</option> 

</select>
        <input type="number" name="precoDespesa" placeholder="R$" id="valor" step=".01" required placeholder="Insira um valor!">
        <p><input type="text" name="limiteDespesa" id="limite" readonly value="Limite de R$30"></p>

<script>
  let tipoDespesa = document.getElementsByName("tipoDespesa")[0]
function mudaLimiteDespesa(valor){
  let limiteDespesa = document.getElementsByName("limiteDespesa")[0];
  limiteDespesa.value = valor
}
 tipoDespesa.addEventListener("change", function(despesa){
   switch(tipoDespesa.value) {
  case "Almoço":
    mudaLimiteDespesa("Limite de R$30")
    break;
  case "Jantar":
     mudaLimiteDespesa("Limite de R$20")
    break;
  default:
     mudaLimiteDespesa("Limite de R$0")
}
});
</script>
```

Caso não domine js para web segue alguns link que possa te ajudar.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Answer (score 0):

### A solução completa passa por JQUERY

**Ao selecionar uma** `option`

- o `value do input text` muda
- o valor máximo para o `input number` muda
- Ao submeter o formulário só é enviado se a condição `max` (valor máximo) for satisfeita

  - `O atributo max especifica o valor máximo para um elemento <input>`

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 
  $('.select').change(function (e) {
      var selectedIndex = $('select').prop("selectedIndex");
      var selectedOption = $('select').find("option")[selectedIndex];
      
      $('input[type=number]').attr('max', $(selectedOption).data('max'));
      
      $("#limite").val("Limite de R$" + this.value);
      
  });
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form>
 
 <select size="1" name="options" class="select">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Tipo</option>
   <option value="20" data-max="20">Almoço</option>
   <option value="30" data-max="30">Janta</option>
 </select>
 
      <input type="number" name="precoDespesa" placeholder="R$" id="valor" step=".01" required min="1" max="30">
      <p><input type="text" name="limiteDespesa" id="limite" readonly value="Limite de R$30"></p>
         
 <input type=submit>
 
 </form>
```